# security issue with app loaded within iframe

Tags: php, security, iframe

I'm working on an application that is loaded inside iframe within other web page. When user launches application I got request to my app like this one:

www.mypage.com/?user=1234

Then my app redirects user to

https://login.host.com/oauth2?response=code&client_id=my_app_id&scope=&
redirect_url=www.mypage.com/?index/loadApp

Given user id is used to check if there is already token in DB, if not - received code is used to receive new access token.

Question is following:
How do I prevent calls that aren't going from i-frame on www.host.com? Request "www.mypage.com/?user=1234" can be seen in firebug console, so, if someone manually enters  this url in browser, he can launch app for random user. Whats more, if there will be found such token in DB, person will see this random user data!

I use request signing for all my requests. But I dont know what to do with this first request (www.mypage.com/?user=1234).

Whats is the best practice in such cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, in essence, that your site isn't using any authentication for that first request! You need to come up with some scheme for the other web page to sign the request, and verify that signature before performing the redirect.

(Additionally, make sure that the URL that's being redirected to performs appropriate authentication as well...)